# R SHINY: Clear/ update mainPanel depending on selectInput/numericInput choice

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, excelr

I'm pretty new to shiny (being playing around for about a week). And I'm trying to create an app that takes and input tab-separated text file and perform several exploratory functions. In this case I'm presenting a very simplified version of that app just to highlight what I want to do in a specific case:

Problem:

If you try the app with the sample data (or any data in the same format) you can notice that the app effectively performs the default summary table (if `selectInput="summarize"`, then `output$sumfile)`, but when you try to select "explore", the previous table gets removed from the mainPanel, and outputs the full file (`selectInput="explore"`,then `output$gridfile`) in the place where it would be as if `selectInput="summarize"` was still selected.

If you re-select "summarize", `excelOutput("sumfile")` gets duplicated on the mainPanel.

My goal is simple:

`excelOutput("sumfile")` when `selectInput="summarize"` ONLY and

`excelOutput("gridfile")` when `selectInput="explore"` ONLY

without placement issues or duplications on the mainPanel

So far I've tried:

```
inFile=input$df

if(is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

if(input$show=="summarize") 
  return(NULL)
```

or

```
inFile=input$df

if(is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

if(input$show=="explore") 
     return(NULL)
```

To control what shows up on the mainPanel, but with placement and duplication issues.

sample data:

```
#Build test data
testdat<-data.frame(W=c(rep("A",3),
                        rep("B",3),
                        rep("C",3)),
                    X=c(letters[1:9]),
                    Y=c(11:19),
                    Z=c(letters[1:7],"",NA),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#Export test data
write.table(testdat,
            "your/path/file.txt",
            row.names = FALSE,
            sep = "\t",
            quote = FALSE,
            na="")
```

shiny app (app.R):

```
library(shiny)
library(excelR)

#function to summarize tables
Pivot<-function(df){
  cclass<-as.character(sapply(df,
                              class))
  df.1<-apply(df,
              2,
              function(x) unlist(list(nrows = as.numeric(NROW(x)),
                                      nrows.unique = length(unique(x))-(sum(is.na(x))+length(which(x==""))),
                                      nrows.empty = (sum(is.na(x))+length(which(x==""))))))

  df.2<-data.frame(df.1,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df.3<-data.frame(t(df.2),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df.3$col.class<-cclass
  df.3$col.name<-row.names(df.3)
  row.names(df.3)<-NULL
  df.3<-df.3[c(5,4,1,2,3)]
  return(df.3)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel(title=h1("Summary generator",
                                      align="center")),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      h3("Loading panel",
                         align="center"),
                      fileInput("df", 
                                "Choose file (format: file.txt)",
                                accept = c("plain/text",
                                           ".txt")),
                      selectInput("show",
                                  "Choose what to do with file",
                                  choices=c("summarize","explore")),
                      p("**'summarize' will output a summary of the selected table"),
                      p("**'explore' will output the full selected editable table"),

                      tags$hr()

                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      excelOutput("gridfile"),
                      excelOutput("sumfile")
                    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  dat<-reactive({
    fp<-input$df$datapath
    read.delim(fp, 
               quote="", 
               na.strings="\"\"", 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })
  #get summary
  output$sumfile<-renderExcel({
    inFile=input$df

    if(is.null(inFile)) #if fileInput is empty return nothing
      return(NULL)

    if(input$show=="explore") #if selectInput = "explore" return nothing
      return(NULL)

    dat.1<-data.frame(dat())
    dat.2<-Pivot(dat.1)
    excelTable(dat.2,
               defaultColWidth = 100,
               search = TRUE)

  })
  #get full file
  output$gridfile<-renderExcel({
    inFile=input$df

    if(is.null(inFile)) #if fileInput is empty return nothing
      return(NULL)

    if(input$show=="summarize") #if selectInput = "summarize" return nothing
      return(NULL)
    dat.1<-data.frame(dat())
    excelTable(dat.1,
               defaultColWidth = 100,
               search = TRUE)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The previous table gets removed because you are returning null when the other option is selected. Instead of that you should check if the rendered table is null.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to use `observeEvent` for your inputs `input$show` and `input$df` and `renderExcel` based on your selection of `input$show. Here is an updated version for your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(excelR)

#function to summarize tables
Pivot<-function(df){
  cclass<-as.character(sapply(df,
                              class))
  df.1<-apply(df,
              2,
              function(x) unlist(list(nrows = as.numeric(NROW(x)),
                                      nrows.unique = length(unique(x))-(sum(is.na(x))+length(which(x==""))),
                                      nrows.empty = (sum(is.na(x))+length(which(x==""))))))

  df.2<-data.frame(df.1,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df.3<-data.frame(t(df.2),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df.3$col.class<-cclass
  df.3$col.name<-row.names(df.3)
  row.names(df.3)<-NULL
  df.3<-df.3[c(5,4,1,2,3)]
  return(df.3)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel(title=h1("Summary generator",
                                      align="center")),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      h3("Loading panel",
                         align="center"),
                      fileInput("df",
                                "Choose file (format: file.txt)",
                                accept = c("plain/text",
                                           ".txt")),
                      selectInput("show",
                                  "Choose what to do with file",
                                  choices=c("summarize","explore")),
                      p("**'summarize' will output a summary of the selected table"),
                      p("**'explore' will output the full selected editable table"),

                      tags$hr()

                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      excelOutput("gridfile"),
                      excelOutput("sumfile")
                    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  dat<-reactive({
    fp<-input$df$datapath
    read.delim(fp,
               quote="",
               na.strings="\"\"",
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent({
    input$show
    input$df
    }, {
    inFile=input$df
    if(is.null(inFile)) #if fileInput is empty return nothing
      return(NULL)

    if(input$show=="explore") {
      output$gridfile<-renderExcel({

        dat.1<-data.frame(dat())
        excelTable(dat.1,
                   defaultColWidth = 100,
                   search = TRUE)

      })
    }

    if(input$show=="summarize") {
      output$sumfile<-renderExcel({

        dat.1<-data.frame(dat())
        dat.2<-Pivot(dat.1)
        excelTable(dat.2,
                   defaultColWidth = 100,
                   search = TRUE)

      })
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!